# Adding an "s" character at the end of the opening brace of a method on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

Why when Adding an "s" character at the end of the opening brace of a method, i get an error that has no connection with the problem itself! :

[image]

Comment: Because it botches the parsing. The compiler doesn't read the code in the same way as you do.

Comment: yes, i knew that humain is not like machine !!,  but i want to knew if is it a bug ? when we develop, we should create a clean code, with perfect control of any situation, It is my boss who insists on this fact, except that big software suffers from this kind of problem, I seek an opinion of an expert, and I chose exlipse as an example. thank you for your reply.

Comment: No, that is not a bug in Eclipse. Think about it: in practice it would be impossible to give a clear error message for any arbitrary kind of garbage that you put in. You'd have to have a computer that was as smart as a human to be able to have that...

Comment: thank you for your participation on this topic @Jesper

Answer (score 0):

I am  %90 percent sure that Eclipse gives that error because s is at the same line with the method and it is an invalid syntax. If you write s to another line it would give error to it too. Because you have an error at the same line wiith method declaration, Eclipse gives error to everywhere you try to use that method. If you write s to the end of a statement like

```
int x = 5;s
```

It would give error to everywhere you try to use x. And I assume it would say something like x is undefined.